# Insertion of dynamic select list in HTML code in ApEx

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex

Let's say I make a dynamic select list in shared components, and then I need to insert the dynamic select list in my HTML code. Is there any method to insert it in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Let say we have following LOV with name `MY_LOV`:

```
select 'Red' d, 1 r from dual
 union all
select 'Green', 2   from dual
 union all
select 'Blue',  3   from dual
```

Its HTML code will be:

```
<select name="f01" >
  <option value="%null%" selected="selected">%</option>
  <option value="1" >Red</option>
  <option value="2" >Green</option>
  <option value="3" >Blue</option>
</select>
```

So it is a bit difficult to write this HTML manually, but you can generate HTML code in PL/SQL block. You need package [apex_item](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192). It has a number of functions, that generate HTML code of all standard elements. For select lists you can use one of following functions:

- SELECT_LIST
- SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV
- SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV_XL
- SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY
- SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY_XL

In your case, you need `SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV` or `SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV_XL`.
You need change your region type to `PL/SQL` and write following as source code for a region:

```
begin
  htp.p(apex_item.SELECT_LIST_FROM_LOV(p_idx => 1, p_lov => 'MY_LOV'));
end;
```

Also you need to know: package `apex_application` has a number of variables with names `g_fXX`, where `XX` - number between 1 and 50. These variables are used for data exchange between server and browser. In my example of PL/SQL code `1` - is a number of such variable (as well as `f01` in the example of HTML code above). You need to choose a number, that is not busy on your page.